# Finding the Timedelta through pandas dataframe, I keep return NaT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

So I am reading in a csv file of a 30 minute timeseries going from "2015-01-01 00:00" upto and including "2020-12-31 23:30". There are five sets of these timeseries, each being at a certain location, and there are 105215 rows going down for each 30 minutes. My job is to go through and find the timedelta between each row, for each column. It should be 30 minutes for each one, except sometimes it isn't, and I have to find that.

So far I'm reading in the data fine via

```
ca_time = np.array(ca.iloc[0:, 1], dtype= "datetime64")
ny_time = np.array(ny.iloc[0:, 1], dtype = "datetime64")
tx_time = np.array(tx.iloc[0:, 1], dtype = "datetime64")

#I'm then passing these to a pandas dataframe for more convenient manipulation


frame_ca = pd.DataFrame(data = ca_time, dtype = "datetime64[s]")
frame_ny = pd.DataFrame(data = ny_time, dtype = "datetime64[s]")
frame_tx = pd.DataFrame(data = tx_time, dtype = "datetime64[s]")

#Then concatenating them into an array with 100k+ rows, and the five columns represent each location

full_array = pd.concat([frame_ca, frame_ny, frame_tx], axis = 1)
```

I now want to find the timedelta between each cell for each respective location.

Currently I'm trying this as a simply test

```
first_row = full_array2.loc[1:1, :1]
second_row = full_array2.loc[2:2, :1]

delta = first_row - second_row
```

I'm getting back

```
    0   0   0   
1 NaT NaT NaT 
2 NaT NaT NaT
```

These seems simple enough but don't know how I'm getting Not a Time here.

For reference, below are both those rows I'm trying to subtract

```
              ca                   ny                   tx                   fl                  az
1 2015-01-01 01:00:00 2015-01-01 01:00:00 2015-01-01 01:00:00 2015-01-01 01:00:00 2015-01-01 01:00:00,                     0                   0                   0                   0                   0
2 2015-01-01 01:30:00 2015-01-01 01:30:00 2015-01-01 01:30:00 2015-01-01 01:30:00 2015-01-01 01:30:00
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Advice: you should reformat your question into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you'll have more chances to get a nice answer

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to simplify it as much as possible while still trying to get my message across I hope

Comment: How exactly is the CSV file structured and how are you reading it?

Comment: Each CSV file is structured as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` and I'm reading it in as `datetime64[s]`

Comment: Have you looked at using pandas `diff` to get the difference between the values in the rows?